# R or id Cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse

I have this problem with my android source in Eclipse. I tried to import com.R; but only the R cannot be resolved disappeared.  I got the id cannot be resolved now. I "developed" in Eclipse with Android a few months ago too, but there wasn't the ID cannot be resolved problem. 
What can I do? It is a fresh installed Eclipse+Android ADT+Emulator+ eg...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're not importing `android.R` but instead, your generated R file, i.e. `com.myproject.R`?

Answer (score 1):

I would delete R, And right click your project and go to Android Tools > Fix project properties. That should work.

Comment: @user590898 Try doing that, and then restarting Eclipse

Comment: Thanks, it was good. But after half a minute it make it again. What can be the problem?