# R.java not showing image ID

Tags: android, android-drawable

I copied 2 images to one of the drawable folder, but the id's not generated in R.java file. Is there any short cut to find the ID's?

Comment: Refresh the `Res` folder or just whole project. They'll show up.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R or id Cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323891/r-or-id-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

Just clean the project and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the project select project->Menu->project->clean selected project
2. Create a new workspace and add the backup copy of your project at newly one
3. Check drawable folders may have png images with not valid names or resources

Comment: I tried all the above but, closing the workspace and reopen it works or me, thank you